# Unsatisfied dependencies for type String Jboss6

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss6.x

Getting error, not sure why since I'm using `beans.xml` in both modules effected.

> WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [String] with qualifiers [@SystemProperty] at injection point [[parameter 1] of [constructor] @Inject public com.comp.alert.EmailAlertHandler(String, String)]

SystemProperty.java:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface SystemProperty {

    @Nonbinding String value();

}
```

EmailAlertHandler.java (only included part of the code that uses @Systemproperty:

```
@Email
@Stateless
public class EmailAlertHandler implements AlertHandler {

    @Inject
    public EmailAlertHandler(@SystemProperty("min.email.from") String emailFrom,
                             @SystemProperty("min.email.to") String emailTo) {
        this.emailFrom = emailFrom;
        this.emailTo = emailTo;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendAlert(Alert alert) {
        //body omitted 
    }
}
```

beans.xml that is defined in the module for EmailAlertHandler:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd"/>
```

beans.xml that is definied in the module for SystemProperty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd"/>
```

EmailAlertHandler is injected here. The sendAlertAsync method being called in another class to essentially kick off the functionality:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class AlertManager {

    @Inject @Email
    private AlertHandler emailAlertHandler;

    @Asynchronous
    public void sendAlertAsync(Alert alert) {
        // Handle alert via email
        emailAlertHandler.sendAlert(alert);
    }

}
```

Essentially all solutions I have already found on similar unsatisfied/missing dependency errors point to configuring beans.xml but that hasn't solved anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like nothing produces these Strings.

Do you have producers?

You can try with:

```
public class PropertyProducer {

     @Produces
     public String createProperty(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
         String value =injectionPoint.getAnnotation(SystemProperty.class).value();
         return System.getProperty(value);
     }
}
```